# Class file version 61 but should be 55 in IntelliJ configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have this problem where I try to build my Spring project in Java 11, but for some reason IntelliJ compiles the class in Java 17 thus the version of the class file in [pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnQNB.png) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlGqi.png) [my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlgje.png). I also wanted to dockerize the application, but I get the same error  [dockerization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtDO3.png)  [java version in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgayf.png)

I need to build my Docker application but there is error in Java version files, why does IntelliJ build the class files in Java 17 (class file version 61) but not 11 when I set it.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0 uses Spring 6, and both require Java 17 as the minimum version as they have been compiled for that version. If you want to use Spring Boot 3.0, you need to use Java 17. If you want to continue using Java 11, you need to switch to Spring Boot 2.7.

Comment: And for future reference, please don't post screenshots for textual information like pom.xml, exception messages, logs and console output. Post it as code formatted text.